# Evaluar formula SI con seleccion multiple

Tags: excel

Cuando empleo esta formula en excel en celdas continuas evaluo si aparace el texto mencionado

```
=SI(J11:J17="palabra";"SI";"NO")
```

Pero en el cuadro de dialogo de excel me muestra varios resultados que son los que me interesa porque quiero tener todas las coincidencias de ese rango, pero cuando le doy enter, solo me muestra una sola respuesta. Como haria en excel para obtener en una sola celda los nombres de todas las filas donde se encontro el texto de interes. Quiero la matriz que me muestra el cuadro de dialogo cuando se esta construyendo la formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien necesitas un listado con los resultados de coincidencia en una celda que satisfaga la condición de que un grupo de celdas contienen el valor "palabra" y sin macro... creo que se require de dos pasos:

Usar referencias explícitas en la columna k por ejemplo

```
SI.ERROR(
         DIRECCION(--(J11="palabra")*CELDA("FILA";J11);
                   --(J11="palabra")*CELDA("COLUMNA";J11);4)
         ;"")
```

Tomando como referencia estos datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego concatenar de K11 a K18 los resultados digamos en la celda K9, en este [post](http://www.raymundoycaza.com/como-concatenar-un-rango-sin-usar-macros/) explican como empleando la función `TRANSPONER` se puede conseguir

```
J11 J12 J14 J16
```

En la celda K9 que se mencionó.

Es importante señalar que el procedimiento descrito en el post antes indicado, no está disponible en Excel 2010 para sistema operativo macOS, porque se necesita de la tecla F9 para que funcione, esta situación es similar con la tecla F4 para fijar las celdas en las formulas de excel.

Comment: Solo una duda mas como aplicas algo asi a un formato condicional. Porque el asunto es establecer un rango dinamico....D2:K9.....pero en vez de fijarlo asi sea resultado de una formula. La idea es establecer el rango con formulas y lo mas cercano fue INDIRECTO, pero en formato condicional lo convierte y no mantiene la formula

Comment: Si es un tema de rango dinámico y formato condicional como indicas, creo que este [post](https://excelforo.blogspot.com/2013/02/formato-condicional-para-un-rango-movil.html) podrá darte un mayor alcance sobre el particular.